# How to read from large process output correctly

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

There are already a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988870/how-to-interact-with-a-process-input-output-in-sbcl-common-lisp) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353353/how-to-process-input-and-output-streams-in-steel-bank-common-lisp) on how to read from a process stream but as far as I can see they do not cover reading from a process which:

- may run for a long time before making any output
- makes a huge output at the end of its lifetime (more than the stream buffer can hold)
- should not run longer than a given time frame
- the resulted output is needed as a whole (long character string)

Therefore using the mentioned solutions would either result in wasted process cycles as the loop will try to read the stream even though there is no output, or the non termination of the solution as the process cannot print its whole output (due to full buffer) and the output handler waits for process termination prior to reading.

My current solution looks like this (inspired by an solution for bulk reading large files)

```
(defun control-process (process timeout)
  (sb-ext:with-timeout timeout
    (handler-case
      (do ((output-stream (sb-ext:process-output process))
           (string nil))
          ((and (equalp (sb-ext:process-status process) :exited)
            (equalp (peek-char nil output-stream nil :eof) :eof))
           (values string :exited))
        (cond 
          ((equalp (sb-ext:process-status process) :signaled)
           (error 'unexpected-process-finish :finish-status :signaled))
          ((equalp (sb-ext:process-status process) :stopped)
           (error 'unexpected-process-finish :finish-status :stopped)))
        (let ((seq (make-string (file-length output-stream))))
          (read-sequence seq output-stream)
          (setf string (concatenate 'string string seq))
          (sleep 1)))
     (sb-ext:timeout (err)
      (declare (ignore err))
      (values nil :timeout))
     (unexpected-process-finish (err)
      (values nil (finish-status err))))))
```

The function is called with a process:

```
(sb-ext:run-program "/path/to/programm"
                           (list "--params" "foo" "bar") 
                           :output :stream :wait nil)
```

But this solution has its drawbacks:

- it does not work as the stream is not associated with a file (error)
- it does a generic sleep of 1 even though there might not be a output at that time
- it does a lot of concatenation which seems to an inelegant solution

Final handling/clean-up of an exited/stopped/too long running process is handled by the calling function.

How can I read from a process which:

- may run for a long time (and does its output at the end of its lifetime)
- may make a output larger than the stream buffer
- must not run longer than a given time span
- output is needed as a whole

?

Comment: Is redirecting the output to a file in the first place, and then reading the file afterward an option?

Comment: as this function will be called A LOT I'd rather not as this would result in a lot of unnecessary writing and reading on the hard drive. Though if there would be a neat hack of having a file in the RAM might actually be an option

Comment: If you're worried about the stream buffer size, you could use a string output stream (possibly with a preallocated string, if you have an idea how big to make it).  Then you wouldn't need to worry about the buffer size.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but relevant, as the question demonstrates the technique used in the answer here, [Reading the binary output of an external program in Common Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8816485/1281433).

Comment: [running shell commands with gnu clisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3019142/1281433) is closer to being a duplicate, but still not quite the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might a string output stream work for you?  The output will be stored in the string that you get back afterward, so the buffering shouldn't be too much of a problem.    E.g.,

```
* (with-output-to-string (out)
    (sb-ext:run-program "/bin/ls" '("/") :output out))

"bin
boot
…
vmlinuz
vmlinuz.old
"
```

If you want to preallocate the string, you can do that to, with [with-output-to-string](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm)'s *string-form* argument.

You don't have to use with-output-to-string to use a string-output-stream, though.  You could also create one with [make-string-output-stream](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_s_2.htm#make-string-output-stream) and pass it to sb-ext:run-program.  You'd get the text out of it eventually with [get-output-stream-string](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_ou.htm#get-output-stream-string).